# How to implement a trait exclusively for type variants where the const generic value satisfies a given condition

Tags: rust

I am working on a custom BigInt implementation based on [Const Generics](https://practice.rs/generics-traits/const-generics.html#:%7E:text=Const%20generics%20are%20generic%20arguments,type%20T%20and%20N%3A%20usize.)

Basically I have a `Uint<BITS, LIMBS>` type that can represent uints of arbitrary size in BITS, by splitting it up into several LIMBS.

For this type I want to implement both the `From` as well as the `TryFrom` trait.
Ideally it should work such that if the BITS value is larger than the number of bytes of the input it should implement `From` otherwise `TryFrom` with a check on wether the value can fit.

For example I want to have `From<u64>` implemented for `Uint` where `BITS >= 64` otherwise I want to implement `TryFrom`.

Below is my attempt using an `IsTrue` trait taken from [this github discussion.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/3162#issuecomment-898846380)
However the compiler fails here because it complains about `TryFrom` being a duplicate implementation of the blanket implementation derived from `From`. (See [this for reference on the TryFrom / From collision problem](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50133))

Any ideas of how to implement the desired behaviour or if it is possible at all ?

```
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

pub struct Uint<const BITS: usize, const LIMBS: usize> {
    limbs: [u64; LIMBS],
}

/// Error for [`TryFrom<T>`][TryFrom] for [`Uint`].
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Hash)]
pub enum ToUintError<T> {
    ValueTooLarge(usize, T),
}

trait IsTrue<const B: bool> {}
impl IsTrue<true> for () {}

impl<const BITS: usize> From<u64> for Uint<BITS, 1>
where
    (): IsTrue<{ BITS >= 64 }>,
{
    fn from(value: u64) -> Self {
        Self { limbs: [value] }
    }
}

impl<const BITS: usize> TryFrom<u64> for Uint<BITS, 1>
where
    (): IsTrue<{ BITS < 64 }>,
{
    type Error = ToUintError<Self>;

    #[inline]
    fn try_from(value: u64) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if value < (1 << BITS) as u64 {
            Ok(Self { limbs: [value] })
        } else {
            Err(ToUintError::ValueTooLarge(BITS, Self { limbs: [value] }))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is based on an attempt to add the respective `From` implementations to the [ruint](https://github.com/recmo/uint) crate. However I reduced the implementations to the minimal example necessary to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The core of this question can be boiled down to: "How do I implement a trait exclusively for type variants where the const generic value satisfies a given condition."

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Even if it is, it will require some serious gymnastics with the type system.